# What would be the best choice to go with? React JWT or Server Side Sessions for authentication?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, authentication, react-router, jwt

I've read several articles, they're saying do not go with JWT as they're not secure. Whereas going with session has a disadvantage that if server is restarted, session will be logged out.

So I want to know what would be the best choice to go with? JWT or Server Side Session, also please do share any reference links so that I could understand and implement.

I'm using MongoDB for user registration. So what should I choose JWT or Server Side Session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There are no right and unique solution for your question*.

You should analyze your use case and make right choice. In order to do that you can consider pros and cons for both solutions.

| Type | Pros | Cons |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JWT | 1) Allow to scale your back-end with stateless authentication 2) You can use the same authentication provider for different applications | 1) The JWT size could be larger than a session ID. It could affect network performance since it is included with each HTTP request. 2) The data stored in the JWT is readable by the client. This may be an issue. 3) In order to revoke a JWT before it expires you need to use a revocation list. This gets you back to the server side storage issues you were trying to avoid. |
| Server Side | 1) Easy to code both the client and server. 2) Easy to destroy a session when someone logs out. | 1) Scalability, because the sessions are stored in the server’s memory, scaling becomes an issue when there is a huge number of users using the system at once. 2) Every HTTP request requires a lookup to the data store |

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @DarioFiore I would choose JWT but the issue with that we cannot immediately revoke the authentication. Suppose a person is admin in the site, and I want to make the person a subscriber, then even after changing the role, I won't be able to stop the person from doing the admin processes.